# tensorflow: comment in inception v3 image_processing.py makes no sense to me

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In `image_preprocessing.image_preprocessing`, the code ends:

```
# Finally, rescale to [-1,1] instead of [0, 1)
image = tf.subtract(image, 0.5)
image = tf.multiply(image, 2.0)
return image
```

This makes no sense to me for two reasons.

First, I can't figure out why the image prior to the rescale is in `[0,1)`.  It looks like the image will have been converted by `decode_jpeg`, which does the obvious thing, and then resized using `tf.images.resize_images`, which often converts to floats, but they seem to me to be in the range `[0,256)`.

Second, I can't figure out what good this linear rescale does in any event.  It seems to me that if you want to rescale, you should probably do something like scikit-learn's [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), so that you reconvert the data to be zero-centered and have uniform standard deviation.  Of course, that's probably a mistake here because the magnitude of color changes is useful in image recognition.

My overall impression is that the comment is wrong, and that the code doing the "adjustment" is in fact irrelevant, because linear transformations don't matter before the first step of a CNN.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Ohh, they (linear transform) do matter! Even for SVMs. Not in theory, thought. Still a difference in practice.